# Ao selecionar uma opção no select trocar os campos do formulário

Tags: javascript, formulário

Estou criando o site de um evento para um amigo, e para o formulario de inscrição tenho a seguinte situação:

```html
<h1>Formulario de Inscrição</h1>
<form name="incrição">
<b>Nome Completo:</b></br> <input type="text" size="100" placeholder="Digite seu nome completo" required></br></br>
<b>Endereço:</b></br> <input type="text" size="100" placeholder="Digite seu endereço - Rua ******** ***** ****** Nº***" required></br></br>
<b>Telefone:</b></br> <input type="text" size="100" placeholder="(DDD) 9XXXX -XXXX" required maxlength="12" >
</br></br>
<b>Incrição para o campeonato de:</b></br>
<select name="Inscrição">
    <option method="post" value="Cosplay" name="Cosplay">Cosplay</option>
    <option method="post" value="Smite" name="Smite">Smite</option>
    <option method="post" value="" name="K-pop">K-Pop</option>
    <option method="post" value="Bey Blade" name="Bey Blade">Bey Blade</option>
    <option method="post" value="Just Dance" name="Just Dance">Just Dance</option>
    <option method="post" value="Quadribol" name="Quadribol">Quadribol Terrestre</option>
    <option method="post" value="Anime Quiz" name="Anime Quiz" value="cosplay">Anime Quiz<option>
    <option method="post" value="Desenho"  name="Desenho" value="cosplay">Competição de Desenho</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Preciso que quando a opção "Cosplay" for selecionada por exemplo, apareçam novos inputs abaixo da opção com novas perguntas, já que cada inscrição tem requisitos diferentes...
 Ex: Personagem:

Comment: Oi Fernanda, bemvinda! Acho que o mais simples é criares o HTML todo e depois ajudar-mos-te a a escondêr (e desabilitar) as partes que nõ são selecionadas. Dessa maneira não precisas de criar elementos novos.

Comment: Boa noite, gostaria de saber se a resposta lhe ajudou, se não por favor comente o que acha que falta.

Answer (score 2):

Você terá que usar um pouco de css e um pouco de js

Notas antes de começar

- Recomendo não usar acentos nos atributos names e ids, ex: troque `<select name="Inscrição">` por `<select name="inscricao">`
- Não use mais de um value dentro de um `<option>`, ex: troque `<option method="post" value="Anime Quiz" name="Anime Quiz" value="cosplay">` por `<option method="post" value="Anime Quiz">`
- Não use nos atributos dos options, o name deve ir dentro do select apenas, ex: troque `<option method="post" value="Cosplay" name="Cosplay">Cosplay</option>` por `<option value="Cosplay">Cosplay</option>`
- Tag `<option>` não deve ter o atributo method, este atributo é apenas para a tag `<form>`
- No exemplo abaixo o atributo `data-` é necessário para detectar os campos que devem ser exibidos.
- Recomendo usar jQuery para facilitar.

Recomendo adicionar a opção selecione, segue um exemplo completo:

```js
$("#selecionar").change(function() {
    var $this, secao, atual, campos;
  
    campos = $("div[data-name]");
    
    campos.addClass("hide");

    if (this.value !== "") {
        secao = $('option[data-section][value="' + this.value + '"]', this).attr("data-section");
      
        atual = campos.filter("[data-name=" + secao + "]");
      
        if (atual.length !== 0) {
            atual.removeClass("hide");
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.hide
{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Formulario de Inscrição</h1>
<form name="incrição">
    <b>Nome Completo:</b></br> <input type="text" size="100" placeholder="Digite seu nome completo" required></br></br>
    <b>Endereço:</b></br> <input type="text" size="100" placeholder="Digite seu endereço - Rua ******** ***** ****** Nº***" required></br></br>
    <b>Telefone:</b></br> <input type="text" size="100" placeholder="(DDD) 9XXXX -XXXX" required maxlength="12" >
    </br></br>
    <b>Incrição para o campeonato de:</b></br>
    <select name="Inscricao" id="selecionar">
        <option value="">Selecionar...</option>
        <option data-section="cosplay" value="Cosplay">Cosplay</option>
        <option data-section="smite" value="Smite">Smite</option>
        <option data-section="k-pop" value="K-pop">K-Pop</option>
        <option data-section="bey-blade" value="Bey Blade">Bey Blade</option>
        <option data-section="just-dance" value="Just Dance">Just Dance</option>
        <option data-section="quadribol" value="Quadribol">Quadribol Terrestre</option>
        <option data-section="anime-quiz" value="Anime Quiz">Anime Quiz<option>
        <option data-section="desenho" value="Desenho">Competição de Desenho</option>
    </select>

    <div data-name="cosplay" class="hide">
        Campos cosplay: <input type="text" value=""><br>
    </div>

    <div data-name="smite" class="hide">
        Campos smite: <input type="text" value=""><br>
    </div>

    <div data-name="k-pop" class="hide">
        Campos kpop: <input type="text" value=""><br>
    </div>

    <div data-name="bey-blade" class="hide">
        campos bey-blade: <input type="text" value=""><br>
    </div>

    <div data-name="just-dance" class="hide">
        just-dance: <input type="text" value=""><br>
    </div>

    <div data-name="quadribol" class="hide">
        quadribol: <input type="text" value=""><br>
    </div>

    <div data-name="anime-quiz" class="hide">
        anime quiz: <input type="text" value=""><br>
    </div>

    <div data-name="desenho" class="hide">
        desenho: <input type="text" value=""><br>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Muito obrigada, entendi mais ou menos o código, mas me explica só mais uma coisa? Para continuar fazendo o formulário se expandir para os outros campos como eu faço?

Comment: Cada um dos campos devera mostrar um tipo de formulário diferente, o cosplay por exemplo pergunta o personagem, o de smite pede os integrantes da equipe e assim por diante, mas ate agora, só consigo usar esse código com um dos option, quando tento executa-lo em mais de um, ele simplesmente não mostra nada...
O que devo fazer nesse caso?

Comment: @FernandaGuedes isto não foi bem especificada na pergunta, mas vou editar e adicionar um exemplo, por favor em quanto isto faça o tour: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Muito Obrigada @GuilhermeNascimeto! Ajudou bastante

Comment: @FernandaGuedes se ajudou, por favor marque a resposta como Correta, fico agradecido